# How to fix 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Problem deserializing property' error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8, spring-data-cassandra

I am converting date string in format yyyy-MM-dd to com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate using object mapper and save that data into Cassandra in my java spring boot project.
The type of my column in Cassandra is date and i am using com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate in my java class.
But while converting map to my java class it throws error "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Problem deserializing property 'employeedateofbirth' (expected type: [simple type, class com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate]; actual type: `java.time.LocalDate`), problem: argument type mismatch". 
I am not using java.time.LocalDate still it gives me argument mismatch error.

I even tried registering module by using the following code

```
ObjectMapper oMapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule()).registerModule(new Jdk8Module()).registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
oMapper.findAndRegisterModules();
```

I have also tried some configuration for object mapper like

```
oMapper.configure(MapperFeature.USE_GETTERS_AS_SETTERS, false) ;
```

Even used annotation on my attribute:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDate employeedateofbirth;
```

But nothing seems to work for me. Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message indicates, there is a type mismatch. Change this in your target class:

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate;
```

into:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
```